# Как исправить ошибку? Мучаюсь пару дней

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fourth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Выполнение программы 429");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        int n, m, d, e;
        d = 0;
        e = 0;
        System.out.println("Введите n:");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Введите массив а:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Введите m:");
        m = scan.nextInt();
        int[] b = new int[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            b[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        ;
        int[] c = new int[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            c[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        if (min(a) > 10) {
            System.out.println(min(b) + min(c));
        } else {
            System.out.println(1 + max(c) ^ 2);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    static int max(final int[] mas) {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            if (s < a[i]) {
                s = a[i];
            }
        }

        return s;
    }

    static int min(final int[] mas) {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            if (s > a[i]) {
                if (s = 0) {
                    s = a[i];
                }
                s = a[i];
            }
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:
error: '{' expected
public class fourth.java

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, но else вроде не нужно в скобках писать, но это не точно)

Comment: На какой строчке?

Comment: public class fourth здесь

Comment: А если убрать `public` перед `class fourth`?

Comment: спасибо EOF, вроде помогло

Comment: воспользуйтесь нормальной IDE (например, Intellij Idea), она вам большинство ошибок подсветит

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко, вижу в коде только один else и он написан верно.

Answer (score 0):

Переименуй файл в `fourth.java` - кажется, у тебя сейчас `fourth.java.java`.

И включи отображение расширений в винде.